# Why is my setenv() call not working?

Tags: c, bash

I wrote the following C code to set the env variable to `\x09`. But when I use `echo $EGG | hexdump`, I see that it sets it to `00`. This problem happens only when the first nibble is zero. Any clue what is wrong?

```
char shellcode[] = "\x09";

main() {
    setenv("EGG", shellcode, 1);
    system("/bin/bash");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: my question has nothing to do with the above question.

Comment: You should terminate the string (char shellcode[]) with the 0 (NULL) character.

Comment: @axeoth String literals are always terminated, except when used to inialize an array of the non-terminated length.

Comment: @unwind: mea culpa, you are right. I saw a literal character (between aprostrophes). I was wrong.

Comment: @Veger That's definitly not a dupe.

Comment: Do a `set | grep EGG` (before leaving the shell) and you'll see it worked.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that characters `0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c ...` are considered whitespace characters and are stripped from a variable value. If you try to set `0x01`, it'll be visible in the shell.

P.S. It looks like the variable *is* set to `\x09` but is not echoed by the shell: 
Indeed:

```
prev_sh_$ ./so2 
$ export IFS=" \n"
$ echo $EGG | hexdump
0000000 0a09                                   
0000002
```

`0x0a` (`\n`) is added by the shell to print the value on the next line.

Comment: Can you show documentation about this behavior? I cannot seem to find it

Comment: @Veger See: `man bash` (section `Word Splitting`); The env/ var/ `IFS` can be used to change this behaviour (for `bash` at least). Anyway, the man page states that only the characters set by `IFS` are swollowed away.

Comment: Ah... it is actually properly set, but striped the shell. I was looking at the `setenv()` documentation which did not mention anything about disallowed characters.

Comment: The problem is that then I then try to yield $EGG as an argument to another program and the problem still holds. For instance, if I use ./prog $EGG, when I debug it, in  argv[1], 0x09 is replaced by 00, even if IFS is set as described above.

Comment: Rather than modify `IFS`, just quote the value of `$EGG`: `echo "$EGG" | hexdump`

Comment: thanks chepner, I was giving a big hex string to my prog, and forgot that some of those machine instructions can be in fact the ascii equivalent of space or tab. Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your code works correctly ;)

`0x09` is the ASCII code <kbd>tab</kbd> key.

So `EGG` is set to <kbd>tab</kbd> key. When you print it, it actually prints <kbd>tab</kbd> which you don't normally recognize in the console.

Comment: The OP is piping the echo output to `hexdump`, so the tab should be visible?

Comment: @Veger Earl answered that I guess.